# CSS Formatting problem oxes not inline

Tags: css

The boxes were on one line now they have been knocked onto three why is this?

CSS:

```
#case_studies { margin:10px 0 0 5px; }  
            .case_study { float:left; width:258px; padding-left:19px; }             
            #case_studies .strip { width:279px; height:30px; margin:15px 0 20px -19px; }
                #case_studies h3.tri { background:transparent url("../images/ico_triangle.gif") no-repeat left; font-size:1.3em; padding:10px 0 10px 20px; }
            #case_studies .content img { margin-bottom:10px; }
                .light_green img { border:1px solid #7ac63c; }
                .light_orange img { border:1px solid #fa7605; }
                .light_blue img { border:1px solid #4dacd8; }

            #case_studies .green { background:#7ac63c url("../images/bg-greenstrip.gif") repeat 0 0; height:40px;}
                #case_studies a.green { background:transparent; text-decoration: underline; color:#7ac63c; }
                .light_green { background:#def1ce; width:260px; margin:0 15px 15px 0; } 

            #case_studies .orange { background:#82c1f1 url("../images/bg-orangestrip.gif") repeat 0 0; height:40px; }
                #case_studies a.orange { background:transparent; text-decoration: underline; color:#fa7605; }
                .light_orange { background:#feddc0; width:260px; margin:0 15px 15px 0; }    

            #case_studies .blue { background:#82c1f1 url("../images/bg-bluestrip.gif") repeat 0 0; height:40px;}
                #case_studies a.blue { background:transparent; text-decoration: underline; color:#4dacd8; }
                .light_blue { background:#d2eaf5; width:260px; margin:0 15px 15px 0; }  
            .case .content { padding:10px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="case_studies">     
    <div class="case_study light_green">
        <div class="strip green"><h3 class="tri">Industrial</h3></div>
        <div class="content case">
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                <?php query_posts('category_name=Industrial&showposts=1'); if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <img src="<?php $key="case-study"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="244" height="132" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                    <?php the_content(__('')); ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div><!-- Featured Box END --> 

    <div class="case_study light_orange">
        <div class="strip orange"><h3 class="tri">Commercial</h3></div>
        <div class="content case">
             <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                <?php query_posts('category_name=Commercial&showposts=1'); if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <img src="<?php $key="case-study"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="244" height="132" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                    <?php the_content(__('')); ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div><!-- Featured Box END -->         

    <div class="case_study light_blue">
        <div class="strip blue"><h3 class="tri">Domestic</h3></div>
        <div class="content case">  
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                <?php query_posts('category_name=Domestic&showposts=1'); if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <img src="<?php $key="case-study"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="244" height="132" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                    <?php the_content(__('')); ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div><!-- Featured Box END --> 
</div>
```

Comment: (-1) Please add a screen shot or a link to a live example. This code is *extremely* hard to read, and the PHP parts are entirely meaningless to the issue.

Comment: Try getting the generated HTML instead. Isolating the problem down to fewer lines of code would also be nice.

Comment: Create a demo with http://jsfiddle.net/ for example.

Comment: here you go: http://fluroltd.com/clients/harveys/case-studies/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in http://fluroltd.com/clients/harveys/wp-content/themes/harveys/css/base.css you have:

```
#page_case_studys { float:left; width:400px; margin-left:10px; }
```

Which forces the following containers into that box. Since 260*3 = 780, you need at -least- a box of 780 pixels, not including any extra padding or margin.

If you specifically need #page_case_studys to have a width of 400px throughout your website, I would suggest writing a more specific CSS style for the page to target the element and set the width to auto.

Also, the boxes all have a width of 260 because of the following rule in the same stylesheet:

```
.light_green { background:#def1ce; width:260px; margin:0 15px 15px 0; }
```

If you're using Firefox, download Firebug and use that to help solve your CSS issues. In Chrome, you can right-click the element and go to "Inspect Element".

Related links:

http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html

Comment: Thank you that was my mistake I changed it my accident thank you.

Comment: An added comment to this: When you have four style sheets (five if you count the one it can't find) being loaded at the same time, all of which play with the same element, you're going to have a hard time tracking down the issue if you aren't using a tool to help you. It's even worse when you nest elements in multiple divs, each with their own width and margin setting. The deeper you go, the more confusing it gets.

Comment: You still need to change the width on #page_case_studys. I would suggest removing the width entirely, as doing so fixes the issue in Chrome.

<pedantic>Also, it should be #page_case_studies.</pedantic>

Answer (score 0):

In base.css, line 79 you have:

```
#page_case_studys {
float:left;
margin-left:10px;
width:400px;
}
```

You should increase the witdh to make room for all the 3 boxes.